# Make TextView adjustable with ellipsis at the end for the largest font size checked in Accessibility Settings

Tags: android, textview, android-textview-autosize

- I've got `TextView` with description (anything from 1 line to 10+ lines)
- I want text to be clearly visible if I change font size `Settings -> Accessibility -> Font Size` to `Largest`
- I have some space, but not enough to display whole description
- I choose 6 lines as maximum to display
- I want to ellipsize at the end of description

TL;DR: **if text is too long I expect lines < 6 and ellipsis at the end.** Which doesn't happen (photo below). How to have `TextView` with lines number adjust to text length and always add ellipsis at the end?

**How do you approach such problem? Maybe I should think of from different perspective? Which one? Or maybe I try to eat cake and have cake in the same time?**

DETAILS:

Aforementioned `TextView` inside `ConstaintLayout` (that's why `android:layout_width/height="0dp"`)

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_list_item_description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="6"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="14sp"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        <!-- some constraints -->
        tools:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum." />
```

What happens:
[image: Text is trimmed at 6 line which is ugly. And not ellipsize.]

Then I've changed `autoSizeMinTextSize` to `"10sp"` and it happened that all of descriptions managed to match into `TextView` and had nice ellipsize, but font became too small for people with eyes disability.